# How to make a distance between <li> tags?

Tags: html, css

I am a self-learner to try to make an website, however I am not sure how I should make a space in between those two li tags. here is more detail (https://jsfiddle.net/1dgyhxso/)
Simply I want a border on "my account" and a border on "Log out" to have some space in between them and align center well. Can anyone give me advice? I tried border-right: negative numbs but it does not works.

Also, since I just learn HTML/CSS, my code might look inefficient. Is there any tips you guys can give me in order to prevent the repeat?

```css
.card {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  color: #666;
  padding-top: 25px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: 145px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  border: 4px solid #e3e3e3;
  width: 170px;
  height: 230px;
  border-width: 1px;
}

.card li {
  border: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
  border-radius: 4px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 15px;
  width: 65px;
  height: 20px;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  margin-left: 29px;
  letter-spacing: normal;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666;
}

li {
  float: left;
  margin-right: -33px;
  margin-left: 35px;
  color: #666;
  font-family: 'source_sans_proregular';
  font-size: 12px;
  letter-spacing: -0.5px;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <img src="../image/login.png" class="picture">
  <p class="nickname">nickname</p>
  <p class="school">name</p>
  <p class="school">ID</p>
  <li><a href="/my" class="one">My account</a></li>
  <li><a href="/user/logout" class="two">Log out</a></li>
</div>
```

Comment: you need to put ```<li>``` in ```<ul>```tage. If you want space between the lis first do what I said then after each li add a ```<br>``` tag

Comment: @codingwith3dv `br` tags are **not intended for spacing** - That's what padding or margin are for.

Answer (score 0):

At first you need to put `<li>` between `<ul>`  tags then targert `.card ul li` and apply the css

Answer (score 0):

You have added so many unwanted CSS , You can simply do both way, horizontal and vertical

**Vertical - One below the Other**

```css
.card {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      text-align: center;
      color:#666;
      padding: 5px;
      display: block;
      margin-left: 145px;
      margin-top: 30px;
      border: 4px solid #e3e3e3;
      width: 170px;
      height: 230px;
      border-width: 1px;
      }
      
.card li {
  border: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
  border-radius: 4px; 
  height: 20px;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  margin: 3px;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}
ul {
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="card">
    <img src="../image/login.png" class="picture">
      <p class="nickname">nickname</p>
      <p class="school">name</p>
      <p class="school">ID</p>

    <div>
       <ul>
          <li><a href="/my" class="one">My account</a></li>
          <li><a href="/user/logout" class="two">Log out</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
 </div>
```

**Horizontal - Side by Side** *We use `display:inline`* for `<li>` tags

```css
.card {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  color:#666;
  padding: 5px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: 145px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  border: 4px solid #e3e3e3;
  width: 170px;
  height: 230px;
  border-width: 1px;
}

.card li {
  border: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
  border-radius: 4px; 
  height: 20px;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 5px;
  display: inline;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}
ul {
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="card">
    <img src="../image/login.png" class="picture">
    <p class="nickname">nickname</p>
    <p class="school">name</p>
    <p class="school">ID</p>

  <div>
     <ul>
        <li><a href="/my" class="one">My account</a></li>
        <li><a href="/user/logout" class="two">Log out</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `inline-block` display property and remove unnecessary padding & margin. `float` is creating problems in your code, remove it and use `display: inline-block`.

```css
.card li {
  border: 1px solid #d6d6d6; 
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;

  width: 65px;
  height:20px;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding:5px;

  letter-spacing: normal;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666;
}

li {
  color: #666;
  font-family: 'source_sans_proregular';
  font-size: 12px;
  letter-spacing: -0.5px;
  list-style: none;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Li into Ul

```css
.card {
  text-align: center;
  color: #666;
  padding: 25px;
  display: block;
  margin: 30px auto;
  border: 4px solid #e3e3e3;
  width: fit-content;
  height: 230px;
  border-width: 1px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666;
  word-wrap: none;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  border: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 15px;
  height: 20px;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 5px;
  letter-spacing: normal;

}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <img src="../image/login.png" class="picture">
  <p class="nickname">nickname</p>
  <p class="school">name</p>
  <p class="school">ID</p>
  <ul>
      <li><a href="/my" class="one">My account</a></li>
  <li><a href="/user/logout" class="two">Log out</a></li>
  </ul>

</div>
```